# Numpy array value change via two index sets

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
    # Before
    raw = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

    # Set values to 10
    indice_set1 = np.array([0, 2, 4])
    indice_set2 = np.array([0, 1])
    raw[indice_set1][indice_set2] = 10

    # Result
    print(raw)
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But the raw values remain exactly the same.

Expecting this:

```
    # After
    raw = np.array([10, 1, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: by doing `raw[indice_set1]` you generate a new array, which is the one you modify with the second slicing

Comment: raw[indice_set1] = 10  would change the original one to -> array([10,  1, 10,  3, 10,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])    How can I add second layer of indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing `raw[indice_set1]` you get a **new array**, which is the one you modify with the second slicing, not `raw`.

Instead, slice the slicer:

```
raw[indice_set1[indice_set2]] = 10
```

Modified `raw`:

```
array([10,  1, 10,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```

Comment: Fantastic, you are better than chatGPT.

Comment: @arapEST given all the very bad chatGPT answers that have flooded the site lately, I hope so :p

Comment: By the way that example was copied straight out of the chatGPT convo :) But, on some other cases I've got a lot of useful correct solutions from that bot.